# I cannot get webpack to work

Tags: webpack, dojo

I am starting on Dojo 2. I set up a new site using

```
dojo create --name fiasco
```

I then run

```
dojo build -w
```

which gives the following

```
i cli-build-app: 1.0.0
i typescript: 2.6.2
√ hash: dfd4cdebaf73f96105b6
× errors: 0
‼ warnings: 0

chunks:
main     runtime
assets:
2xS-3HMh.svg (107.52kb) / (74.23kb gz)
main.c0d35a640e95e6b3596b7273758a5eae.bundle.css (1.02kb) / (0.51kb gz)
main.c0d35a640e95e6b3596b7273758a5eae.bundle.css.map (1.49kb) / (0.61kb gz)
main.e140c18f63636d46e088.bundle.js (97.33kb) / (26.83kb gz)
main.e140c18f63636d46e088.bundle.js.map (390.82kb) / (90.14kb gz)
manifest.json (0.41kb) / (0.19kb gz)
runtime.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js (1.72kb) / (0.96kb gz)
runtime.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js.map (7.83kb) / (2.68kb gz)
output at: file:///C:\xampp\htdocs\fiasco\output\dist

The build completed successfully.

watching...
```

At this point I go to

```
http://localhost:9999
```

and get the following error:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:9999.
```

From the **watching...**  I assume **webpack** is working. But I cannot see anything on port 9999

Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: Looking into Taskmanager Process it does not show anything for **webpack** or **webpak-dev-server** I am suspecting that I may have installed webpack in the wrong location. I installed it in c:\xampp\htdocs\fiasco the root of my site. I did this by running: **npm install --save-dev webpack** from the root.

Comment: I was so curious about it, so installed cli, created project and got same thing. Looks like http server wasn't started on localhost:9999 but it seems from the docs, that it must. Anyway, you can find you build in \output\dist and open index.html from filesystem, or create own http server using express.js for instance, until we know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial had not been updated inline with the move from the `cli-build-webpack` cli command to the new `cli-build-app` command.

It looks like with the new command you are missing the `--serve` (or `-s`) flag to start the webserver.

You should be able to run `dojo build -h` to discover all the available options for the command.

Hope this helps!